# Multiple modal semantic ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I need help to fix my modal problem with semantic ui. Already search on many resource but no luck. This my html :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.coupled.modal').modal({allowMultiple: false});
  $('.login.modal').modal('attach events', '#login', 'show');
  $('.signup.modal').modal('attach events', '#signup', 'show');
  $('.forgot.modal').modal('attach events', '#forgot', 'show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui center aligned container">
    <div class="ui buttons">
        <button id="login" class="ui button">Login</button>
        <div class="or"></div>
        <button id="signup" class="ui positive button">Signup</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui tiny login coupled modal">
 <div class="description">
   <div class="ui header">login</div>
   <p><a id="signup" href="#">Signup</a></p></p>
   <p><a id="forgot" href="#">Forgot</a></p>
 </div>
</div> 
<div class="ui tiny signup coupled modal">
 <div class="description">
   <div class="ui header">Signup</div>
   <p><a id="login" href="#">Login</a></p></p>
   <p><a id="forgot" href="#">Forgot</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ui tiny forgot coupled modal">
 <div class="description">
   <div class="ui header">Forgot</div>
   <p><a id="signup" href="#">Signup</a></p></p>
   <p><a id="login" href="#">Login</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

What i want if i click signup link on my modal or button, i can see signup modal or if i click login link on any modal, i can see login modal also on forgot link. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you have more than one element with the same id. Per the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) (emphasis mine):

> When specified on HTML elements, **the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s tree** and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

The simplest solution is to turn `signup`, `login` and `forgot` into classes:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui center aligned container">
    <div class="ui buttons">
        <button class="ui button login">Login</button>
        <div class="or"></div>
        <button class="ui positive button signup">Signup</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui tiny login coupled modal">
    <div class="description">
      <div class="ui header">login</div>
      <p><a class="signup" href="#">Signup</a></p></p>
      <p><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot</a></p>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="ui tiny signup coupled modal">
    <div class="description">
      <div class="ui header">Signup</div>
      <p><a class="login" href="#">Login</a></p></p>
      <p><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui tiny forgot coupled modal">
    <div class="description">
      <div class="ui header">Forgot</div>
      <p><a class="signup" href="#">Signup</a></p></p>
      <p><a class="login" href="#">Login</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the JavaScript code, you'll need a different selector (i.e. `.login`, not `#login`). You also need to see `show refresh` instead of `show` as the event triggered - this will ensure a modal will be refreshed if it's already shown (for example, if you go from "Login" to "Forgot", but then go back to "Login").

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.coupled.modal').modal({allowMultiple: false});
        $('.login.modal').modal('attach events', '.login', 'show refresh');
        $('.signup.modal').modal('attach events', '.signup', 'show refresh');
        $('.forgot.modal').modal('attach events', '.forgot', 'show refresh');
});
```